# Calculating direct solar radiation using QGIS and GRASS

Tags: qgis, terrain

I am using QGIS 3.16.8 and GRASS 7.8.5.

I would like to compare two places in my study area climatically. Since both are only a few 100 metres away, I assume that they only differed in terms of slope inclination and slope exposure. Therefore, I would like to calculate the direct solar radiation over the sum of one year.

I tried it with the following function: r.sun.incidout

The layers, however, only have a range from 0 min. to 0 max. (except for the incidence angle raster map).

Beyond that, south is given as 270 ° by default. This confuses me. South would actually be at 180 °.

I already have a digital terrain model with an accuracy of 1x1 metre.

Comment: sin(270°)=-1 because angle is measured counterclockwise from East.

Comment: Consequently, should I keep the default value?